# Formatting history command using \t instead of space as separator

Tags: command-line, bash

Is it possible to format history command output using tab separator instead of space between fields?

I know the variable `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` is there another variable to format the output?

For example:

```
command_number{\t}date_time{\t}command{\n}
```

It doesn't have to be a specific shell.

Comment: does not apply for fish: fish history just prints the command. fish does not have history expansion, so `!<number>` does not apply

Comment: `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` is unique to Bash. It does not exist in other shells.

Comment: Check if `history | column -t` is the output you are looking for (you might have to install package `bsdmainutils`), and if yes, define a shell alias or function that does that.

Comment: @HuHa it's not, since this command replaces the space in each command with a tab also.

Comment: Why would you need that?  A split to separate id from command seems the more obvious method.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact purpose, here is a way to remove leading whitespaces, and also replace the default "double space" (separating the columns with ID and Command) with a `\t` instead:

```
history | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/ \+ /\t/'
```

The `sed` expression is 2-part:

- `s/^[ \t]*//`: This part removes any leading spaces or tabs (if you for some reason want to start each line with a `\t`, do this instead: `s/^[ \t]*/\t/`).
- `s/ \+ /\t/`: This part replaces 2 or more spaces with a `\t`.

The order is important, since you want to *first* remove any leading whitespaces, and *afterwards* replace any 2 or more spaces with `\t`. If you just run the 2nd part, you also risk getting `\t` at the beginning of lines with smaller ID numbers.

With this, you hopefully have some building blocks to continue customizing your command. If you also want to add timestamp to the history, it gets a little more complicated, since there are additional single spaces separating the columns.

*A little inspiration came [from this post](https://superuser.com/questions/241018/how-to-replace-multiple-spaces-by-one-tab).*